# Find eigenvalues/vectors of $A=\mathbf{u}\mathbf{v}^T+\mathbf{v}\mathbf{u}^T$ where $\mathbf{u},\mathbf{v}$ are orthonormal

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, orthonormal, symmetric-matrices

Our problem is to compute the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of two matrices formed by products of orthonormal vectors, $\mathbf{u}$ and $\mathbf{v}$:

$A=\mathbf{u}\mathbf{v}^T+\mathbf{v}\mathbf{u}^T$

$B=\mathbf{u}\mathbf{v}^T-\mathbf{v}\mathbf{u}^T$

I started with trying to find the eigenvalues/vectors of A, but I am getting stuck. First, I define the vectors and compute A:

$\mathbf{u}=\begin{bmatrix} u_1 \\ u_2 \\ \vdots \\ u_n\end{bmatrix}$ and $\mathbf{v}=\begin{bmatrix} v_1 \\ v_2 \\ \vdots \\ v_n\end{bmatrix}$

$A=
\begin{bmatrix}
    2u_1v_1 & u_1v_2+v_1u_2 & \dots  & u_1v_n+v_1u_n \\
    u_2v_1+v_2u_1 & 2u_2v_2 & \dots  & u_2v_n+v_2u_n \\
    \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
    u_nv_1+v_nu_1 & u_nv_2+v_nu_2 & \dots  & 2u_nv_n
\end{bmatrix}$

Our eigenvalue/vector problem is $A\mathbf{w}=\lambda \mathbf{w}$ and I know we find the eigenvalues/vectors by setting $|(A-\lambda I)|=0$

I thought that I might be able to figure it out if I started first with a $2\times2$ matrix, but even that was overwhelming. My determinant is $(2u_1v_1-1)(2u_2v_2-1)-(u_2v_1+v_2u_1)(u_1v_2+v_1u_2)$, which I set to zero. Expanding that out gives an even more terrible equation.

I know that A is a symmetric matrix, so all of the eigenvalues are real, but I have no clue how to figure out what they are. I also tried to start by setting $\mathbf{u}, \mathbf{v}$ to be the standard basis vectors $\in \mathbb{R}^2$, but I realized that I would get eigenvalues/vectors specific only to those specific orthonormal vectors. I don't know how to find them in terms of the elements of $\mathbf{u}$ and $\mathbf{v}$.

I have the same problem for B, which is similar to A but with zeros on the diagonal:

$B=
\begin{bmatrix}
    0 & u_1v_2-v_1u_2 & \dots  & u_1v_n-v_1u_n \\
    u_2v_1-v_2u_1 & 0 & \dots  & u_2v_n-v_2u_n \\
    \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
    u_nv_1-v_nu_1 & u_nv_2-v_nu_2 & \dots  & 0
\end{bmatrix}$

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:**  Let $K$ be the base field (I believe you take $K:=\mathbb{C}$).  Suppose that $u,v\in K^n$ satisfy $u^\top\,v=v^\top u=0$ and $u^\top\,u=v^\top\,v=1$.  Then the matrices $A:=u\,v^\top+v\,u^\top$ and $B:=u\,v^\top-v\,u^\top$ are of rank $2$.  Note further that $\text{im}(A)$ and $\text{im}(B)$ equal $\text{span}_K\{u,v\}$.  Thus, $0$ is the eigenvalue of $A$, or $B$, with multiplicity $n-2$.  What are the remaining eigenvalues of $A$, or $B$?  (Observe that, if $-1$ is not a square in $K$, then $B$ is not diagonalizable over $K$.)

Comment: The matrices have rank 2 because they are each a linear combination of only two vectors, correct? I am not sure how you know that 0 is an eigenvalue of A and B and especially do not know how you know its multiplicity. I also don't understand how you know whether B is diagonalizable or not, given that we do not know precisely the vectors $\mathbf{u}$ and $\mathbf{v}$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Use a coordinate system where the first two basis vectors are $\bf u$ and $\bf v$.

${\bf u}^T {\bf v}$ and ${\bf v}^T {\bf u}$ are just the scalar $0$.

Comment: Ah, I mistyped the problem! I meant to type $\mathbf{u}\mathbf{v}^T + \mathbf{v}\mathbf{u}^T$ instead of $\mathbf{u}^T\mathbf{v} + \mathbf{v}^T\mathbf{u}$. In this case, neither values are scalar.

Comment: @cfitz: I would think about this hint some more! Think about what $A,B$ look like with respect to a basis as described here.

Comment: @Sam hmmm... I don't think I'm quite getting it. With $\mathbf{u}$ and $\mathbf{v}$ as basis vectors, that means that $A$ and $B$ are spanned by $\mathbf{u}$ and $\mathbf{v}$, right? So the basis vectors of $A$ and $B$ are  $\mathbf{u}$ and $\mathbf{v}$?

Comment: @kales: If $\vec{u}=\vec{e}_1$, and $\vec{e}_1, \dots, \vec{e}_n$ is a basis, then what are the components of $\vec{u}$ wrt.  $\vec{e}_1, \dots, \vec{e}_n$? What is the representation of $\vec{u}=\vec{e}_2$? Correspondingly, what is the representation of $A,B$?